# .htaccess on redirect loop when changing subdomain to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I'm using htaccess to change the 'm' subdomain to the 'mobile' subdirectory.

I've created this code to run in Htaccess but it is returning an inside loop.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) mobile/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I'm attempting to redirect all file requests with the 'm' subdomain to go to the 'mobile' directory.

error.log

```
[Thu Jan 15 19:01:29 2015] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

How would I go about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!mobile/).*)$ mobile/$1 [NC,L]
```

i.e. route to `/mobile/` only if request doesn't already have `/mobile/`.